# How to add optional parameters with AngularJS router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two Angularjs broadcast options one is for add and other one is for edit for both routing i have different keys to redirect user to the page. For add state `$stateParams` processId is rendered but for edit state ChallengeKey id is undefined. So question is how to defined optional parameters with router so if its edit it can take challengeKey and route it to appropriate page.

so far tried code..

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.$on('addProcessChallenge', function (s,processId){
    $location.path('/addEditChallenge/' + processId);
}

$scope.$on('editPrcChallenge', function (s,chalengeKey){
          $location.path('/addEditChallenge/' + chalengeKey);
}
```

app.js

```
.state('app.addChallenge', {
            url: '/addChallenge/:processId:/challengeKey',
            templateUrl: 'views/processChallenge.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
```

Comment: I'm not sure about adding optional parameters but what about adding a full set of parameters that have default values so they are only picked up when a user decides to add them?